# Why is this python WMI call giving me an error?

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, wmi, python-2.5

Ok, I am pretty clueless here. I use the python WMI module to do the following command:

```
    sj = wmi.Win32_ScheduledJob
    sj.Create("cmd", 0x40000000, 32, 1, 0, "******153000.000000-420")
```

And that gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
        sj.Create("cmd", 0x40000000, 32, 1, 0, "******153000.000000-420")
      File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 431, in __call__
        handle_com_error ()
      File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
        raise klass (com_error=err)
    x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,         u'SWbemProperty', u'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)>
```

Ok, so could you tell me what arguments I am providing wrong? Please give me sample code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it make any difference if you format the StartTime argument with **8** initial `*` characters instead of 6?

I just notice that the [Win32_ScheduledJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation seems to indicate 8 *s, in place of the omitted `YYYYMMDD` characters...